# Is this Application Insight / Azure Functions Bug? or My understanding is incorrect

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Today I integrate my Azure function with Application insight for application logging, especially to capture error stack-trace.

First I have written Azure function without try-catch block so It was showing correct status/Information in Monitor section and application insight as well.

Later I added try-catch block and logged some more data like

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    log.Error(inputData);
    log.Error(ex.Message);
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
```

You can see in below attachment, ResultCode is 500 with Green Status... Why?
I think because of this issue Application Insight not showing this data in Error/Failed request query.

[image]

No record found in Application Insight

```
exceptions
|where operation_Id == "c5b5a345-fa11-4356-b769-b34d1c6619e5" 
| order by timestamp desc 
| project operation_Id , timestamp
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Success check denotes whether your Azure Function call succeeded (= no exception thrown) or failed (= exception thrown).

At your first invocation, an exception occurred, so function invocation didn't terminate normally, thus red checkmark.

When you catch and return 500 manually, that's still OK in terms of function invocation - it finished and returned the result back.

Functions runtime doesn't follow HTTP semantics, the rules are universal for all trigger types.

Application Insight Default metrics won't show handled exception in failed request graph, Developer need build query for handled exception e.g.

```
requests
| where success == "False" and timestamp >= ago(7d) 
| join kind= inner traces on operation_Id  
| project operation_Id , timestamp, message, severityLevel  
| order  by timestamp, operation_Id

severityLevel :- 1 = Info and 3 = Error
```

Comment: I agree Function runtime doesn't follow HTTP semantics, but what about my exception information which I logged? Is it mean we should not use try-catch in Azure function

Comment: @PankajRawat I think `log.Error` doesn't log "exception" but rather trace (?) Exception has stack trace etc, which you don't provide

Comment: Try passing the exception along with your call to Error. Like `log.Error(ex.Message, ex)`. I believe that will flow everything to App Insights.

Comment: I've passed the exception and still have success 500, is it possible to change the behavior to log with success false? https://ibb.co/6NMY8ny

Comment: I also faced the same issue, but I am not sure why even explicitly rethrowing `throw` the exception making it a success. How `throw` is different than the exception without try-catch?