# Azure function success status is true even when result code is 500

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions

I've got an azure function that contains some logic with a pretty basic try catch (code shortened for brevity)

```
    try {
        // do logic here that can potentially fail
    } catch (ex) {
        context.log(`Log details about the exception: ${ex.message}`);
        context.res = {
            status: 500,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json" 
            },
            body: {
                message: ex.message
            }
        };

        return;
    }
```

So in the event of an exception during that logic I handle the exception and gracefully return in the http response and terminate the app. I would expect that azure functions would consider 500 status code's as failure (considering they're internal server errors), but my function is still considered to have successfully executed. Considering this a low volume function with somewhat high importance for it's context, I was to be notified about all failures.

What's the intelligent thing to do error? Do I throw an exception here instead of simply returning?

Comment: Are you see the status from the Monitor tab of azure function?

Comment: Yes, that is the status I'm referring to and that appears to be the one that is used in azure monitor rule evaluation.

Comment: Hello, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) if it's helpful? And if you still have more issues, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is the internal behavior of azure function status check.

**1**.If your code handles the error by using `try catch block` and return 500 manually, azure function considers it as success.

**2**.But if the error is not handled by the code using `try catch block`, it will be marked as failed.

Refer to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51647196/10185816) for more details.